# map, class, member function

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, member-functions

I need help figuring out how to call a member function of a class being held inside of a map.

Basically I have a map containing an object and I am trying to call one of its member function by I keep getting compiler errors I can't deal with.
Here is an example of the code for the function call I currently have.

```
map<int, DailyReport> statContainer;    
for (auto x : statContainer)
    {
        if (x.first < yearAfter && x.first > year)
        {

            daycounter += 1;
            fullYearHtemp += x.second.getHighTemp;
            fullYearLtemp += x.second.getLowTemp;
            fullYearPercip += x.second.getPercip;
        }
    }
```

Is this even possible? Am I going about it all wrong?

EDIT: getHighTemp, getLowTemp, and getPercip are all member function of the class DailyReport. I need to access the functions while the DailyReport object is inside of the map.

Comment: Are `getHeightTemp`, `getLowPercent`, etc. members or member functions?

Comment: Sorry for failing to clarify that, they are member functions.

Answer (score 1):

Should this be `x.second.getHighTemp();` (note the brackets)? Because `getHighTemp()` is a member function .

Comment: Wow, can't believe i spent the last hour and a half searching online and staring at it only to finally give up and come on here to ask my first ever question for it to be something that face-palm worthy obvious. ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to call those as member functions, so you need to append `()` to their names, something like:

```
map<int, DailyReport> statContainer;
for (auto x : statContainer)
    {
        if (x.first < yearAfter && x.first > year)
        {

            daycounter += 1;
            fullYearHtemp += x.second.getHighTemp();
            fullYearLtemp += x.second.getLowTemp();
            fullYearPercip += x.second.getPercip();
        }
    }
```